# How to plot custom formulas using kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

There are three fields a, b, c in my elasticsearch data strore and I'm running kibana on it.I can plot line charts such that either a or b on y-axis and c on x-axis.I want to plot a line chart such that I have sum(a)/uniqueCount(b) on Y-axis and c on X-axis.What should I do for this?

Comment: After lot of research,  I found that it is not possible to perform above type of operations in Kibana.